# python Dlib save face descriptor into file for ulterior use

Tags: python, vector, face-recognition, dlib

I am using Dlib tool of face clustering with python (code in this link https://github.com/davisking/dlib)

I want to save the descriptors in a database then use them to compute the distance between new faces and face dataset.

How can I parse those vectors saved in the database as simple arrays into descriptors with class _dlib_pybind11.vector

Answer (score 1):

I run about this function

```
 descriptor = dlib.vector([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ...])
```

that does exactly what I want